# Lombok with Spring Tool Suite 4

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, lombok

I've recently installed the new Spring Tool Suite 4 in macOS High Sierra but when I tried to run Lombok's installation it wouldn't find my STS installation,

I followed this steps for manual installation (adding -javaagent to the ini file) but with no luck: https://www.edvpfau.de/sts-spring-tool-suite-4-mit-lombok/.

Any idea?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I did install `Lombok` in `Spring Tool Suite 4` just some days ago for Mac and Windows.
And none problems.

**One**:

Execute `java -jar lombok.jar`

- **Note**: normally or by default, it does not find the installer, it is the common scenario in my experience.

**Two**:

Press the `Specify Location` button. Therefore proceed to find and select the `STS.ini` file. It could be `SpringToolSuite4.ini` too.

- **Note:** for `Mac`, go to the `Contents` directory within the `.app` file

**Conclusion:** therefore for any OS, the goal is find the *unique* file with the `.ini` extension

Normally I do this with the IDE closed.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel, I also suggest to install the current Edge version of Lombok because it solves some issues with Eclipse Photon

Comment: Agree, but I have assumed the latest version of Lombok was used.

Comment: In Spring Tool Suite 4 the name changed from STS.ini to SpringToolSuite4.ini at least for MacOs

Comment: MAKE SURE YOU ARE IN `/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app` and NOT `/Applications/STS.app`... If you have an older version of STS, it will show that as the dir... Delete that first before installing lombok

Comment: Using lombok `1.18.10` I break SpringToolSuite4 and it can no longer start. Using `1.18.4` everything works fine. My STS version is `4.4.1.RELEASE`.

Comment: Consider to report that error either in STS or Lombok github accounts

Comment: Using lombok 1.18.10 works fine with STS 4.4.2.RELEASE in MacOs Catalina.

Comment: STS4 installation is picky and sometimes machine dependent. About 1 month ago, I installed on 3 machines simultaneously. All were running the same version of windows 10. For some reason, there was no setup required for one of the machines, but for the other two I had to tweak the .ini configuration file to get it to launch.

Comment: I'll just add that in my case, on a Mac, I did this with STS running. I had to restart STS in order for the installation to work.

Comment: added lombok-1.18.30 to sts-4.20.0 successfully on windows. Make sure -javaagent: lombok.jar is added in the sts.ini file

Answer (score 33):

Although this might be late, but it can be of help for others just experiencing this. Bellow is how I solved this issue

**STEP 1**

Find lombok in your project maven directory -> Right click -> Run As -> Java Application
[image]

**STEP 2**
Click on Specify Location button to choose the path where STS is installed

[image]

**STEP 3**
Go to Application/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuit4.ini Then click on Install -> Quick Installer
[image]

**STEP 4**
Restart STS you good to go

Comment: MAKE SURE YOU ARE IN `/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app` and NOT `/Applications/STS.app`

Comment: This along with the below link worked for me [ renaming to STS.ini ]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523530/lombok-installation-in-spring-tool-suite-4-for-windows

Answer (score 25):

I renamed **SpringToolSuite4.exe** and **SpringToolSuite4.ini** to **STS.exe** and **STS.ini**.  Then used lombok installer's Specify Location to find them.  After lombok installed, I renamed those files back to their original names.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is not upvoted. This is the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I was using SpringToolSuite4 and on executing jar lombok was not able to find IDE at specified location. This answer helped me. Must be given a try and must be upvoted if anybody having same trouble.

Comment: Even this works without renaming back to the original names :)

Comment: latest update: Installer able to pick up the name SpringToolSuite4.exe. No longer need to rename it to STS

Comment: Strange!!! but working !tried so many times with different answers, but this one helped me..without renaming to SpringToolSuite4.(use STS)

Comment: HA!  Can't believe this actually worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 11):

I faced same issue with for Spring tool suite 4

Solution

1. Close running STS.
2. Open terminal
3. Go to    ~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/**version**
4. Run java -jar    lombok-**version**.jar 
   Pop window will come.
5. If it does not pick up the STS itself. Then chose specify location 
   Choose    SpringToolSuite4.ini at ⁨Applications⁩ ▸ ⁨SpringToolSuite4⁩ ▸    ⁨Contents⁩ ▸ ⁨Eclipse⁩ .
6. Click install
7. After this Starts Spring tool suite and clean project.

Comment: Project -> clean was my last missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: After cleaning project it started working.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add to M. Jordan's and prodigy's answer, please be sure to give execute permission to lombok.jar

(After you follow the above-mentioned step) Open terminal and change directory to the content of SpringToolSuite.app

```
cd /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse
```

Then check whether execute permission is available to *lombok.jar*

```
ls -al
```

If you see -rw-r--r-- it means you need to give execute permission

```
chmod +x lombok.jar
```

alternatively you could also do

```
chmod +x /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

Then restart STS

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't been able to use Lombok for ages and your solution helped me solve it.

Answer (score 6):

> > I'll show you how to completely install lombok into Spring Tool Suite 4 or latest version. First go to your project pom.xml file and add this dependency on dependencies section.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

> > Go to your project root folder on your IDE and click the right button on it. Select like below:

[image]

> > And make sure, checked Force Update of Snapshots/Releases. Click Ok to download and update dependencies.

[image]

> > After finishing all task. Go to project Maven Dependencies and find lombok.jar file (>Maven Dependencies >lombok.jar). Right click on lombok jar. Go to Run As Java Application.

[image]

[image]

> > It will open lombok installer window and click ok. Then click Specify Location button.

[image]

> > Select the location where your STS bundle was installed. If it is selected properly then it will checked STS.exe, like below:

[image]

[image]

> > Then click install/update button. Finally lombok will be installed successfully.

[image]

Hopefully it helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

None of the steps worked for me as the file dialog box won't even let me select the directory containing the `SpringToolSuite4.ini`

So I did the following:

1. Get `lombok-<version>.jar` from either your `~/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/<latest-version>/`
   If not available you can get it from mvn repository:
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.6
2. copy the `lombok-<version>.jar` to `/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse` as `lombok.jar`

   ```
   cp /path/to/lombok.jar /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/
   ```
3. Edit the file: `/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuite4.ini` inside the directory to add this last line:

   ```
   -javaagent:/Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse/lombok.jar
   ```
4. Open your project in eclipse. Right click on Maven -> update project. Follow similar step if you're using another build tool (like Gradle)

Comment: correct. It helped and worked for me as I was also not able to select the .ini file in the mac. Would be glad to know why is that so?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, Lombok 1.16 could not locate **STS 4** installation even after pointing to it manually. Worked only after I tried with updated Lombok version - **Lombok 1.18**.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn off STS
2. Install lombok following other common guidances with jar.
3. Turn on STS

Answer (score 1):

I spent like 3 or 4 hours looking for a solution to the Lombok problem with springo book and eclipse, the solution I found on the internet was the following, I leave the link: (https://projectlombok.org/all-
versions) where is the entire Lombok version and I chose the latest lombok version then updated the IDE and MVN and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

**For Latest Mac OS Big Sur**

Just place lombok jar In Application folder then Follow the steps

folder path /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse
once you complete all the steps restart your IDE

1.[image]

2[image]

3.[image]

4.[image]

5.[image]

6.[image]

Comment: Are you certain this will hold up @abhinavxeon? In my experience any changes to any file inside the Springsource app will sooner rather than later trigger some kind of OS protection that will prohibit further launches until you reinstall. At least this is true when running the aarch64 version.

Comment: it using it ! its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way you can do is that by running the following command on command prompt

```
java -jar (jar location/lombok.1.8.1.jar) install (the path where you installed Spring tool suite(STS))
```

for example:

```
java -jar C:\Users\karthick\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.8\lombok-1.18.8.jar install D:\STS_Tool\spring-tool-suite-4-4.1.2.RELEASE-e4.10.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.1.2.RELEASE
```

after that, you have to restart the tool.

Answer (score 0):

on macOS Catalina all I had to do was to use lombok 1.18 and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a different way. just did the below.

1. Copy the lombok.jar to the root directory of STS
2. Added "-javaagent:lombok-1.16.18.jar" to the SpringToolSuite4.ini

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with STS-4.6 and lombok-1.18.18 on Windows10. I added lombok dependency to pom.xml, built the project, ran lombok jar in .m2 repository and restarted STS. Building the project did not work. Finally, Project -> Build All worked.

Answer (score 0):

after install lombok project into your eclipse--
Go to the eclipse sts4 folder--

get the permission to the lombok.jar

$chmod +x lombok.jar

then open the eclipse.

Comment: While this probably won't hurt I checked the permissions on "lombok.jar" in a working lombok install inside Eclipse, rather than the Springsource build, and they are ``-rw-r--r--``.

Answer (score 0):

Step to add lombok project in your eclipse--

download lombok jar and place one folder.

edit the SpringToolSuite4.ini file which is exist in the eclipse folder.

add three lines in last of file--
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-javaagent:/spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE-e4.19.0-linux.gtk.x86_64/sts-4.10.0.RELEASE/plugins/org.projectlombok.agent_1.18.20/lombok.jar

restart the eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

best option is through install new software option built in ecliplse
help>install new software> and add this site https://projectlombok.org/p2
you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Although this might be late, but it can be of help for others just experiencing this. Bellow is how I solved this issue

STEP 1

Find lombok in your project maven directory -> Right click -> Run As -> Java Application enter image description here

STEP 2 Click on Specify Location button to choose the path where STS is installed

enter image description here[image]
Install -> Install/Update Installer
[image]

STEP 3 Go to Application/Contents/Eclipse/SpringToolSuit4.ini Then click on Install/update
[image]

STEP 4 Restart STS you good to go

Restart your IDE and Run Project->Update Maven Project and then all your errors will be gone