# Use Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor without @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lombok

"I am currently learning English and this is my first time writing in English. Please bear with me as there may be some mistakes.

I am attempting to use STS4 to display a list of database information in a browser. However, trying to use Lombok in the UserService.java class does not work.

Specifically, writing just one constructor in the UserService.java class, such as private final UserRepository userRepository; does not work.

Below are the steps I have already taken:

I added the following two lines of code to the application.properties file spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false. spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

Removed lombok.jar from the SpringToolSuite4.ini file and removed the lombok.jar import information. The software was then reinstalled by entering https://projectlombok.org/p2 for STS4 in HELP > Install New Software. The installation completed successfully.

The version of Lombok was specified as 1.18.30 in the pom.xml file, but the problem was not resolved. The error message was ‘Duplicating managed version 1.18.30 for lombok’. So this was not relevant.

I suspect that the STS4 IDE does not handle import statements and annotations correctly, because when I wrote private final UserRepository userRepository; I got an error message that the statement could not be null I got a warning message saying that the statement cannot be null.

Can anyone please give me some feedback on this? Thank you in advance."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autowire the dependency using `@RequiredArgConstructor` in your service class you can do it this way:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    // Your methods here
}
```

regarding this problem:

> The version of Lombok was specified as 1.18.30 in the pom.xml file,
> but the problem was not resolved. The error message was ‘Duplicating
> managed version 1.18.30 for lombok’.

It suggests that this version is already managed elsewhere in your Maven configuration. So if I understand you correctly you just added the Lombok library manually and also added it as a dependency to your `pom.xml` file which most probably caused this issue.
Can you run the following command in the terminal and show here the output:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Please keep in mind if you did add your lombok jar file manually to the classpath you don't need to add lombok dependency to `pom.xml` file.
This is because the jar is already available to your project

I recommend you configure your dependencies using `pom.xml` you don't need to manually manage your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems there I was a slight mistake in my previous message. The main issue appears to be with the following code:

Comment: // This line seems to be causing an error: "The blank final field userRepository may not have been initialized."
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: At first glance I don't see any problems with your code, it looks like a problem with your IDE, could you please read this and try to do the same:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780535/lombok-with-spring-tool-suite-4