# Maven compiler not adding getters/setters(generated using Lombok) to the build jar file

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I have the below Pojo class to which I have added the `@Data` from `Lombok`.

The Project is working fine in Eclipse IDE, and I can even see the getters/setters in the outline window of IDE. But, when I am running `mvn clean install` or `Run As Maven Install` from IDE, the jar file gets generated without any error, but there are no methods(`getters`, `setters`, `equals`, `hashcode`) which are generated by the `Lombok`.
[image: outline window]

Since, IDE is showing the methods, there must be some issue with the maven compiler plugin in the POM file. I tried every possible solution from SO, but nothing worked.

Here is the POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.3.0.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>


</project>
```

I have pushed the test project to the [Github](https://github.com/Puspendert/test-lambok). Can be cloned from here: https://github.com/Puspendert/test-lambok.git

**Update**: To verify if the generation of getter/setter would effect anything, I changed the main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        User user = new User();     
        user.setName("hero");
        System.out.println(user.getName());

    }    
}
```

and boom, as expected the project gave compilation error on `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] Building test-boot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ example ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ example ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/puspender/git/test-lambok/test-boot/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/puspender/git/test-lambok/test-boot/src/main/java/com/example/TestBootApplication.java:[11,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setName(java.lang.String)
  location: variable user of type com.example.User
[ERROR] /Users/puspender/git/test-lambok/test-boot/src/main/java/com/example/TestBootApplication.java:[12,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getName()
  location: variable user of type com.example.User
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Please suggest, what could be wrong here?

Comment: You installed the lombok plugins and stuff in Eclipse, right? I know IntelliJ supports it out-of-the-box but the last time I tried in Eclipse you had to do a manual install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are explicitly disabling annotation processing!

`<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>`

Remove this line - lombok is an annotation processing library after all - and everything (should) work file

**EDIT**: for fairness, there's another deleted answer (for some reason) which also suggests that

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Actually I copied the compiler plugin code from somewhere. Could you please tell what `-proc:none` means?

Comment: On short, It tells the compiler to ignore annotation processong tools such as lombok