# Does Lombok's @AllArgsConstructor Autowire the fields in spring boot automatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I am following a YouTube tutorial to build a spring boot application. The person used lombok and so he didn't had the  `@Autowired` annotation on any field of the class and his code works fine. However when I tried the same, the console shows the service is null.

Appropriate code and Output Screenshot attached for reference.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private AppUserService appUserService;  
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptpasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(appUserService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptpasswordEncoder);
    return provider;
}
```

}

[image: Console Output]

On removing the `@AllArgsConstructor`, and using the `@Autowired` annotation my code works.

So,
Does using lombok dependency with spring boot auto wires the fields automatically? if yes then what mistake am I doing?

PS : I am using Java 11 with Spring boot 2.4.5 on STS 4

Comment: You don't need autowired, just constructor injection

Comment: i know, but thats exactly the problem lombok should provide the constructor automatically

Comment: Since Spring 4.3, it is no longer needed to use `@Autowired` if there is only 1 constructor. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092751/spring-injects-dependencies-in-constructor-without-autowired-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842751/lombok-not-working-with-sts) its a problem of lombok with STS. To use lombok in STS, we need to do the following

1. Copy the lombok jar from the .m2 folder to the place where STS is installed
2. Rename the jar as `lombok.jar`
3. Find the `SpringToolSuite4.ini` file (generally in the same folder) and add  this line `-javaagent:lombok.jar` to the end of the file.
4. Restart STS