# The method getType() is undefined for the type Ingredient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
package tacos.web;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import tacos.Ingredient;
import tacos.Ingredient.Type;
import tacos.Taco;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/design")
@SessionAttributes("tacoOrder")
public class DesignTacoController {

@ModelAttribute
public void addIngredientsToModel(Model model) {
        List<Ingredient> ingredients = Arrays.asList(
          new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
          new Ingredient("COTO", "Corn Tortilla", Type.WRAP),
          new Ingredient("GRBF", "Ground Beef", Type.PROTEIN),
          new Ingredient("CARN", "Carnitas", Type.PROTEIN),
          new Ingredient("TMTO", "Diced Tomatoes", Type.VEGGIES),
          new Ingredient("LETC", "Lettuce", Type.VEGGIES),
          new Ingredient("CHED", "Cheddar", Type.CHEESE),
          new Ingredient("JACK", "Monterrey Jack", Type.CHEESE),
          new Ingredient("SLSA", "Salsa", Type.SAUCE),
          new Ingredient("SRCR", "Sour Cream", Type.SAUCE)
        );

        Type[] types = Ingredient.Type.values();
        for (Type type : types) {
          model.addAttribute(type.toString().toLowerCase(),
              filterByType(ingredients, type));
        }
}
  @GetMapping
  public String showDesignForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("taco", new Taco());
    return "design";
  }

  private Iterable<Ingredient> filterByType(
      List<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
    return ingredients
              .stream()
              .filter(x -> x.getType().equals(type))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

}
```

I was going through the book Spring in action edition 6 chapter. In that in the filterByType method the '.getType()' is showing the error

```
The method getType() is undefined for the type Ingredient
```

I thought it was the error due to lombok but I have installed that as well. I have also import the package 'java.lang.reflect.Field' but still getting the error.

```
package tacos;

import lombok.Data;


@Data
public class Ingredient {
 public Ingredient(String string, String string2, Type wrap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

private final String id = "";
 private final String name = "";
 private final Type type = null;
 
 public  enum Type {
     WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
 }
}
```

The above class is the Ingredient Class

Comment: can you post a link to a cloneable repo?

Comment: post please `Ingredient` class, you said it is annotated with lombok?

Comment: @pleft I have posted the Ingredient class.

Comment: Is this error shown on your IDE (and which is it) or also when you try to compile/run the project from command line? E.g. if it is maven project run from cmd `mvn clean package` ?

Comment: error is shown on my IDE. @pleft

Comment: Which is your IDE?

Comment: Currently I am using Spring Tool Suite

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45217624/3635454

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237030/discussion-between-shantanu-srivastava-and-pleft).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are not the first person who faced with this issue https://coderanch.com/t/730026/java/lombok

> In addIngredientsToModel of class DesignTacoController the flagged
> error is "The constructor Ingredient(String, String, Ingredient.Type)
> is undefined". **Also, in method filterByType the flagged error is "The**
> **method getType() is undefined for the type Ingredient**". It zappears
> that lombok is just not working. But I have lombok in the pom:

Answer:

> Just adding Lombok as a dependency does not make Eclipse recognize it,
> you'll need a plugin for that. See https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide
> for instructions on installing Lombok into Eclipse (and IntelliJ for
> those who prefer it).

Comment: But I have installed the Lombok in STS

Comment: Seems like I have an issue with the dependency which I have added in the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not problem of lombok. It is because there is no getType() function in
Ingredient class. Add getType() funtion will fix the problem.

```
public class Ingredient {
  
  private final String id;
  private final String name;
  private final Type type;
  
  public Ingredient(String id, String name, Type type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
      }
  
  public enum Type {
    WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
  }
  
  *public Type getType() {
      return this.type;
  }*

}
```