# Invalid property of bean class is not writable or an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, methods, inject

This may looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21613703/4506140). But this is different.
I was trying to refactor my legacy code by using method injection in spring.

I have a bean class which contains many static helper methods. My targeted method as follows:

Context.java

---

```
private static MessageSender messageSender;

//...

public static MessageSender getMessageSender(){
    return messageSender;
}
```

Context bean

---

```
<bean id="context" class="org.abc.Context">

   <property name="messageSender"><ref bean="mailMessageSender"/></property>
</bean>
```

MailMessageSender.java

---

```
public abstract class MailMessageSender{

   protected abstract Session createSession();

   //using createSession() somewhere in this class
}
```

MailMessageSender bean

---

```
<bean id="session" class="javax.mail.Session" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="mailMessageSender" class="org.abc.MailMessageSender">
   <lookup-method name="createSession" bean="session"/>
</bean>
```

I'm getting invalid property error when I'm installing the project.

Comment: messageSender is not a property. It's a static field. You can't inject static fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject static field, change your variable in Context.java become like this:

```
private MessageSender messageSender;

//...

public MessageSender getMessageSender(){
    return messageSender;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to `getMessageSender()` to remove **static** behavior.