# Spring - method injection for a constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have the below static helper method. I am trying to refactor this method by using Spring's method injection.

```
public static MessageSender getMessageSender(){
    return new MailMessageSender(getMailSession());
}

//getMailSession() is a private static method which used to refresh 
//and return a Session object to the constructor
```

I tried to use beans in this context, but it won't work as my methods are static.

[Here is what I have tried,(asked in a StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43034470/4506140)

**Note:** I have no clear idea how to call my `getMailSession()` and pass that value to `MailMessageSender` constructor while using method injection.

How can I make this above method to use Spring's method injection?

Comment: Please write the reason before you are downvoting the question. Sometimes that reason could be solved by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
<bean id="context" class="org.abc.Context">

   <property name="messageSender"><ref bean="mailMessageSender"/></property>
</bean>
```

**To**

```
<bean id="context" class="org.abc.Context">

   <property name="messageSender1"><ref bean="mailMessageSender"/></property>
</bean>
```

**Then**

Add the following setter method to your class `org.abc.Context`:

```
private void setMessageSender1(MessageSender ms) {
    Context.messageSender = ms;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, how the `getMailSession()` is getting called and where do I configure it?